# ¿Cómo puedo aumentar los recursos en Data Factory?

Tags: azure, data, factory

Tengo un pipeline heredado que tarda bastante (unas 10 horas) en ejecutar una serie de movimientos de datos, ¿cómo puedo aumentar los recursos para que tarde menos?